# How much cost to buy Conditions from other mantles in Dresden Files Accelerated?

Tags: fate, dresden-files-accelerated

When customizing characters, some players may want to get Conditions, not only Stunts, from other mantles. For example, in my campaign, I have a character with the *Law Enforcement* mantle that wanted the *Third Eye* condition.

Should he pay **one Refresh** for the Condition as he would for a new Stunt?

And what about more complex Conditions? For example, if someone wants to have *Press Credentials* from the *Reporter Mantle*, it seems it should come with *Off the Air* as well.

Comment: Helpful clarification would be if you were talking about character creation or character progression/advancement. The answer you've gotten so far was about the latter.

Comment: Would be both. Do you feel the cost should be different for creation and advancement? 

Answer (score 5):

You pay one refresh for conditions, another refresh for stunts -- and they're bought separately.

One of the odd things (to me) that I'm still adjusting to is that these purchases aren't 'standard' -- there's a specific milestone type where you can make them.  Making out-of-mantle purchases is therefore an expensive tradeoff.